# No Longer asks user to accept application for new users?

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I used to have this code which sent the user to the normal app acceptance page once they went to my application page on facebook:

```
<?php
$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)."&scope=email,user_photos,friends_photos";
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
} else {
    echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
}
?>
```

With the new SDK I replaced all that with what is below:

```
<?php
require_once('src/facebook.php');
// Create our application instance
// (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based 
// on whether the user is logged in.
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know 
// the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don’t know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

} else {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email,user_photos,friends_photos'));
}
?>
```

My question is do I still need the top code for the correct page to come up which asks the user if they want grant access to my app? With just the bottom code this no longer happens?Iis there a newer way to do it with the new SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix the code first:

```
<?php
require_once('src/facebook.php');
// Create our application instance
// (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
));
$canvas_page = "YOUR_URL_HERE";
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based 
// on whether the user is logged in.
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know 
// the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don’t know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
    try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)).'</pre>';
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>top.location.href='" . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email,user_photos,friends_photos', 'redirect_uri'=>$canvas_page)) . "';</script>";
}
?>
```

**Notes:**

- you need to make sure you are linking to the SDK correctly
- using `$facebook->getUser()` will check the `signed_request` and another sources for a current user
- `getLoginUrl()` will build the login URL for you